# Etymology of 'slap-up'

Tags: etymology, british-english

Apparently this is a peculiarly British term, but we'll sometimes use the phrase 'slap-up' to mean 'excellent', as in:

> That's a slap-up meal!

or

> They held a slap-up do.

What's the origin of the term slap-up?  Nothing obvious comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes originally from a Dickens novel (he probably used a common expression of the time).  He used the expression "Slap-bang" to indicate a cheap meal.  Apparently it was "Slap-bang" because people would "bang" the money down for the meal.

Comment: To extend your answer: The term slap-down and bang-down were common at the time and, as you point out, the term slap-bang was a term used for a cheap eatery. This seems to have evolved over time from slap-down as a negative adjective into slap-up as a positive one (and also bang-up, as a more general form) For reasons still obscure to me slap-up is reserved for food whilst bang-up more often refers to a job well done (a bang-up job).

Answer (score 6):

The earliest meaning of *slap up* was to eat. Later it also meant to eat or drink in a hurry, and around the same time meant something exceedingly good.

Could the meaning transferred because a very good meal might be eaten quickly?

---

The [1898](http://www.archive.org/details/witcharacterfol00unkngoog) *Wit, character, folklore & customs of the North Riding of Yorkshire; with a glossary of over 4,000 words and idioms now in use* defines it:

[image: >**Slap up,** *v.* To eat or drink in a hurry. **Slap-up,** *adj.* First-class, exceedingly good. Ex. — *He's gitten a slap-up t'on-oot. Noo that's a slap-upper if ya leyke.*]

The earlier [1828](http://books.google.fi/books?id=mvtaTPSh_1sC&pg=PA135&dq=slap-up&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HDAxT-mwOemh4gSGrqTmBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=slap-up&f=false) *Dialect of Craven, in the westriding of the County of York* has the former meaning:

[image: 3. "To *slap* up," to swallow greedily to dispatch a meal. "He *slapt* up his porridge in a trice," il avala sa soupe dans un moment. *Miege*. To *slappe* up Licher, lapper. *Cotgrave.*]

This meaning *to swallow* is found in a [1709](http://books.google.fi/books?id=g3Ao1l31QLIC&pg=PT1116&dq=%22slap-up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KjQxT4OHCcvE4gSUv6TzBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22slap-up%22&f=false) French-English dictionary, a [1673](http://books.google.fi/books?id=9EI_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PT772&dq=%22slap-up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wjMxT6DfDOqC4gSt3N3xBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22slap-up%22&f=false) dictionary has it meaning *to sustain, to support* (possibly also meaning *to eat*) and in [1660](http://books.google.fi/books?id=PCtWAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PR24&dq=%22slapped-up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-kUxT4eyNsT44QS17qWpBQ&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=%22slap%20up%22&f=false) *to lick*. The *swallow, eat* meaning is printed in several English-French, -Danish, -Swedish, -Italian and Welsh dictionaries.

---

The *exceedingly good* meaning can be found in two 1823 slang dictionaries. *Classical dictionary of the vulgar tongue* by [Francis Grose](http://books.google.com/books?id=bJc-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PT199&dq=%22slap-up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XDcxT5GmFq_74QSt9-ztBA&ved=0CFsQ6AEwCDgU):

[image: slap-up]

And second, in *Slang* by [John Badcock](http://books.google.com/books?id=MbRMAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA161&dq=%22slap-up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XDcxT5GmFq_74QSt9-ztBA&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBzgU), where *bang-up* is defined "quite in fashion, at the top of the mode. All right.":

[image: slap-up]

The first non-dictionary use describes an exceptional boxing match in an [1821](http://books.google.fi/books?id=AL0CAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA292&dq=%22slap-up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Tz0xT5GcNKz44QT06e3nBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22slap%20up%22&f=false) *Sporting Magazine*:

[image: slap up battle]

The next use in prose I found is [1828](http://books.google.fi/books?id=N2MQAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA17&dq=%22slap-up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wzkxT52UIMOH4gTFjdHjBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22slap-up%22&f=false)'s *How to live in London*:

[image]

> gave 250 guineas for what he terms his "slap-up turnout," (*i.e.* handsome cabriolet, with a blood chesnut mare, 15 hands 3 inches, harness, &c.)

Some slightly later books apply *slap-up* to describe someone's fine clothes.

Answer (score 2):

Both Partridge and Green have "slap-up" meaning "first-rate, of superior quality". The earliest reference they cite is from 1829, a little early for Dickens. The "slap-bang shop", a restaurant where one paid in advance, is earlier still (1796), cited in the Lexicon Balatronicum of 1811.

I would think that Green's earliest reference to "slap", the proceeds of a robbery, is the source of the phrase; that first appeared in 1790, apparently.

Comment: Is 1829 a typo? I expect Partridge and Green both found the definitions in each of Grose and Badcock's slang dictionaries, both [1823](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/57337/9001).

Comment: @Hugo, the source cited in Green is "On the Prigging Lay", a translation of "Un jour a la Croix Rouge"; see [here](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Farmer-MusaPedestris/on-the-prigging-lay.html).

Comment: Thanks. And it appears a second time in that translation, on the [next page](http://books.google.fi/books?id=qXADAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA265&dq=%22slap-up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1oIxT5SMKOvT4QTjupGFBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22slap-up%22&f=false).

Answer (score -2):

According to Brewer's Dictionary of Phrase and Fable, SLAP-UP means First Rate,Grand or Lavish. They Quote from Thackeray's "The Newcomes" - 'The more slap-up still have two shields painted on the panel with the coronet over'

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since the author asked for etymology of the word, not its meaning.

Comment: Sorry Vilmar but I must disagree. Etymology relates to source and/or development. The Thackeray quote was, presumably, evidence of usage and thus, to it's possible origin.