# Why are promiscuous women known as "slappers"?

Tags: etymology, british-english, slang, offensive-language

[image]

Women who aren't interested in much more than sex are referred to as "[slappers](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slapper?q=slapper)" in British English.

> *British informal*, *derogatory* a promiscuous or vulgar woman.

Why is this?  I can't find any solid etymology information.

Comment: Is that Dolly Parton?!

Comment: Yeah, "Thanks for the mammaries."

Comment: Yes, it's Dolly Partoon!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OED has this as a draft addition from 2002 (not everything is reproduced here):

> *Brit. slang (derogatory).* A promiscuous woman. Freq. in **old slapper.**
>   See quot. 1990   for a postulated connection with Yiddish schlepper ‘unkempt, scruffy person; gossipy, dowdy woman’; however there is some gap in sense. Cf. also quot. 1854<sup>1</sup> at sense 1.
>
> > 1990   T. Thorne *Bloomsbury Dict. Contemp. Slang* 468/1   *Slapper in British,* a prostitute or slut. This working class term from East London and Essex is probably a corruption of *shlepper* or *schlepper,* a word of Yiddish origin, one of whose meanings is a slovenly or immoral woman.

The 1854 quotes in sense 1 are:

> **1.** *dial.* A large thing or object; a big, strapping, or overgrown person.
>
> > 1854   A. E. Baker Gloss. *Northamptonshire Words,*   Slapper,..applied to persons and things, but most frequently to over-grown females.
> >     1854   A. E. Baker Gloss. *Northamptonshire Words,*   ‘She's a slapper.’

Both etymologies are possible. I guess that “over-grown females” might slap parts of the anatomy against other parts more than smaller women.

From there, it’s but a small step to an assumption of promiscuity and a corresponding shift in meaning. Unfortunately, slang is anything but politically correct.

Comment: Actually the Yiddish to "schlep" might be translated as to "work" (to carry actually, but in a "work" sense). So, a "working" girl?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Indeed. Does German or Yiddish have "working girl" as a euphemism for "prostitute"?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.dict.cc/english-german/working+girl+%5Bprostitute%5D.html). Most (if not all) Yiddish words you know are euphemisms.

Answer (score 5):

There are several possible explanations for the British slang term *slapper*, which some suggest is the equivalent of the American term, [*tramp*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tramp) — *a woman who has sex with many different men*.

1) It could derive from the theatrical expression:

> to slap on the greasepaint

*The Theatre Dictionary: British and American Terms in Drama, Opera, and Ballet* by Wilfred Granville, 1970, [says](http://books.google.it/books?id=d_WCoXDLrEUC&pg=PT108&dq=slap+makeup+origin&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MlbEUp65Fui3yAOI_4CgCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=slap%20makeup%20origin&f=false)

[image]

There is evidence to suggest that the noun *slap* meaning theatrical make-up, existed pre 1860, but was already losing favour in the 19th century.

[image]

Well, that prediction proved to be untrue as shown by [ODC](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slap)

> **Slap** 2 [mass noun] informal make-up, especially when applied thickly or
>   carelessly: *I put a bit of slap on my face and we were ready to go*

Now, anyone who is British-born will be familiar with the notion that *slappers* are supposedly ill-famed for troweling on their make-up, or [*war paint*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/war+paint) if you prefer. Hence, a promiscuous woman is identifiable as someone who slaps on her make-up heavily.

2) The idiomatic expression "**a bit of slap and tickle**" meaning amorous frolicking, with kissing, petting etc. is said to have existed since 1910 in the [*Shorter Slang Dictionary*](http://books.google.it/books?id=Hvxk4FiaATwC&pg=PA193&dq=slap+and+tickle+origin&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uWnEUrvlCqTByQOS-YFw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=slap%20and%20tickle%20origin&f=false) by Paul Beale, and Eric Partridge.

The word *slap* mimics the sound of flesh on flesh, or the sound of heavy breasts slapping together. It could also suggest that a *slapper* is a woman who is [up for](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/up-for) some *slap and tickle*. In other words a willing sexual partner.

3) Finally, in [*Curious English Words and Phrases: The Truth behind the expressions we use*](http://books.google.it/books?id=5utuA8o1LkAC&pg=PA339&lpg=PA339&dq=sliobaire&source=bl&ots=5HpysjjReN&sig=a6jNve8d9FQ77u0UcwRLc7wrb-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=73bGUs2JH6OWywPzj4CYCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sliobaire&f=false)  its author, Max Cryer, suggests that *slapper* could stem from the Irish *sliobaire* meaning *dirty*. In trying to find a direct translation of *sliobaire* I was largely unsuccessful, although I did find this [reference](http://digital.nls.uk/early-gaelic-book-collections/pageturner.cfm?id=76476324&mode=transcription), the *Dictionarium scoto-celticum*:

> **Slìobadh**, -aidh, s. m. et pres. part. v. Sliob. 1.
>   Stroking, act of stroking, or rubbing gently with   the hand : palpandi demulcendi
>   actus. C. S. 2.   Licking, act of licking : lanibendi actus. C. S. 3. 
>   Polishing, act of polishing : laevigandi actus. C. S.
>   **Sliobair**, -e,
>   -ean, s. m. A clumsy, or awkward fel-   low : inconditus, vel inhabilis quis. C. S.

Not being Irish I am unable to ascertain whether these words have any phonetic similarities with "slap" or "slapper".

Comment: Downvoter. What's wrong with explaining why you disagree. I won't bite your head, break down in tears, sulk, or anything.

Comment: I'm Irish, and the word 'sliobaire' is pronounced as 'sluh-ber-eh', with the emphasis on the 'sluh'- the 'eh' is hardly stressed at all so it sounds like an afterthought. Sounds like how an English person might say 'slobberer', so quite similar-sounding to 'slapper'!

Comment: It should be noted that _slìobadh_ and _sliobair_ are not Irish Gaelic, but Scottish Gaelic. They are quite easily transferred to their Irish counterparts, though, which are _slíobadh_ and _sliobaire_. _Slíob_ as a verb means rub, scratch, scrape, polish, smooth, file, grind, lick, pet, pat, extract, or take away and is not related to _sliobaire_ (the accent indicates a long vowel, so the two sound quite different, too). _Sliobaire_ (or _slibire_ in some dialects), which is based on the noun _sliobar_ meaning “anything that hangs loose or untidy, e.g., a cow’s udder”. [cont’d -->]

Comment: [--> cont’d] _Sli(o)b(a)ire_ is a personified noun meaning basically ‘a thingy that hangs sloppily downwards’. It mostly refers to pieces of wood (pliant, dangling rods or pendants, like willow branches) or (animal) body parts like teats and dugs (or “a rope of slime from a cow denoting she is in calf”)—but it can also refer to a person, usually a man, who is tall, gaunt, gangling, and gives the appearance of not having much energy or wit. Derived from that is a verb, _sli(o)b(a)ireáil_ ‘hang about, dawdle’ and a _sli(o)b(a)ireálaí_ is a hangabout or a dawdler. In Standard Irish [cont’d -->]

Comment: [--> cont’d] _sli(o)b(a)ire_ does not have the meaning ‘dirty’, and it would be an odd meaning, considering its derivation; so I would say that the source that claims this etymology is ill-researched and affords little credence on the point. \[All definitions taken from _Foclóir Gaeḋilge agus Béarla_ by Pádraig Ó Duinnín from 1927; an excellent work unfortunately no longer available online, it seems. See also [_slibire_ in Foclóir Gaeilge–Béarla (Ó Dónaill)](http://breis.focloir.ie/en/fgb/slibire) online.]

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh thank you so much! Would *slob* derive from *slíob* by any chance, which in turn led to [*slab*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slab) which M-W says (2) transitive verb, to "put on thickly"?

Comment: You mean the English word _slob_? I highly doubt that. _Slíob_ as a verbal form is only the 2sg. imperative, and it’s pronounced more or less like [ʃliːb], so it’s quite far removed from _slob_. _Sliob(ar)_ is pronounced something like [ʃlʲʌb] or [ʃlʲəb] and would be phonetically closer, but semantically farther away. The earliest citations of _slab_ (in the sense of a slab of wood or metal) have either _slabbe_ or _sclabbe_, which doesn’t fit with the Irish, either. I don’t think there’s a connection.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet pity... when I have some time, I'll edit my post, include your invaluable contribution and do a bit of tiny research too.

Comment: What does it mean in Irish? Is it *dirty* or "something that hangs loosely"

Comment: [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/57337/51214) might also be somewhat/indirectly relevant here.

Comment: @Drew thank you, that's nice of you. I will definitely look into those links sometime tomorrow.