# What's the difference between "slap-up meal" and "gourmet meal"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, differences, british-english

The following quote comes from a collocation book for ESL purposes. I can see it's trying to teach us about the usage of different expressions to describe different kinds of meals.

"Whether you want a **slap-up meal**, a **gourmet meal** or just tasty, home-cooked food, there’s something for everyone in the Old Port restaurant area.

I'm interested in the difference between "slap-up meal" and "gourmet meal". My initial thought after doing some google search is this: A "slap-up meal" is an excellent meal which tends to be heavy and substantial. A "gourmet meal" is also an excellent meal, but usually calls to mind the delicate and exquisite type. Both are tasty of course!

Comment: Her Majesty complimented the chef: "What a slap-up meal!" The Bash Street Gang were in raptures: "Oh, truly a gourmet meal!" "Exquisitely presented!" "Indeed, a repast to remember for many a year."

Comment: [Etymology of 'slap-up' - English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/etymology-of-slap-up)

Comment: I would say that the intended meaning of "slap-up" is apt to be misunderstood in the US.  The expression is not common, and it sounds a lot like the much more common "slap-together", meaning put together at the last moment using what's on hand.

Comment: @Hot Licks Well it is a bit like that, if you read the references to Dickens, in Little Eva's link.

Comment: Suggesting migration to http://cooking.stackexchange.com/ or a  more appropriate Q&A SE site. As far as the English language question is concerned, the Q is GR. ODO: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slap-up

Comment: @Kris, in any case, it's duplicate.

Comment: How odd! I'm very familiar with the phrase _slap-up meal_, and I've used it myself—but always understood and used it in the sense @HotLicks described: something that's been quickly and carelessly slapped together using what was at hand. Seems I've been using it quite differently to most other people, then. Live and learn!

Comment: Very similar thoughts when I first saw "slap-up meal". I was picturing in my head a casual meal consisting of microwave food at best. I wouldn't think it's anything more decent than that. Should I use 'gourmet meal" more often then instead of "slap-up meal", which is obviously too easy to confuse people?

Comment: Dictionary definitions do provide the relevant meaning of *slap-up*, in general terms, but they don't explicitly bring out the difference that the question is about. The OP thus couldn't have found the answer just by consulting a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You have understood the distinction pretty well.

Slap-up has the connotation of self-indulgence, plenty of food of the kind one really enjoys, possibly piled high on a table from which one helps oneself, presentation is not a major factor. Think succulent pies; think Spotted Dick and custard.

You might find [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/etymology-of-slap-up) interesting.

Gourmet is about fine-dining, exquisite presentation, a single carrot placed just-so, foams and gels, foraged herbs, interesting flavour combinations (snails and liquorice anyone?) 14 course tasting menus and a small mortgage to pay for it all.

Comment: Only makes sense if it's a snail-shaped liquorice candy. Foams and gels for presentation? In a bathroom setting?

Comment: Yes Daisy, I agree that it sounds mad, really mad. However it's supposedly very, very good: http://www.thefatduck.co.uk/The-Menus/Tasting-Menu/

Comment: "Spotted Dick", anyone? This is British English and most Brits wouldn't bat an eyelid about its usage for its just the name of a delicious pudding. I am concerned that our American cousins might want to refer the matter to a specialist doctor.

Comment: But that said, I think it's incumbent on me to clarify that an "old slapper" may not want to eat a slap-up meal. There is no connection between these idioms.